How to remap a key in windows to have multiple functions?
On my linux machine, I'm using a tool called evremap to map the caps_lock key to escape when tapped and left_ctrl when held. I wanted to replicate this setup for my windows machine but couldn't find a solution that it efficient and at best can be modified with a simple config file (for evremap i just have to modify the config and restart the service with systemctl). To my knowledge I don't think Xmodmap has this functionality, I'm not even sure if that works on Windows systems.

Maybe AutoHotkey?
